# practice linux for practical use

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have learned and studied linux for 6 months with books like 'The linux commandline'. But, I'm just student, not a business man. When I study linux and do not use it for long time, I always forget things which I learned or studied. Also, after learning bash script language, I always forget things and don't know how I can use bash script for practical use. Don't know where to use.

So, I want to do practice daily many examples which is used in real world. Is the any solution not to forget things and practice many things always??

I know answer about my question is relative. But, I want to hear about opinions and answers to get your help.

Comment: Read the shell questions in this site and **answer** them, even if you do not post the answer, the challenge to build an answer will make you internalize the knowledge. After a while, all the details will be fixed in your "muscle memory" and you will not forget them.

Answer (score 3):

Add the `/linux`, `/bash`, `/shell` tags (and related ones) to your favorites on StackExchange U&L, and read the new questions and answers on a daily basis. That's how I keep up with things and learn something new every day.